# Make text bold and italic

Tags: android, xml, text, bold, italics

Is there anyway to make Android text in the xml file both bold and italics?

***SAMPLE***

Comment: try `<Textview android:textStyle="bolditalic" />`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, just add `android:textStyle="bold|italic"`.

Comment: I believe you can just use textStyle="bolditalic"

Comment: It's referenced [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle), but not listed in the table, but I believe you're correct. Either way should work. :)

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this

```
android:textStyle="italic|bold"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<Textview android:textStyle="bolditalic" ....
```

for more info see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="YOUR_TEXT"
/>
```